# Optimizing images in a jar-file

Tags: java, image, optimization, jar

Is there an advantages to putting all my small widget graphics in one single png-file, which is loaded once, and then creating ImageIcons for buttons and such from sections of this?
(Normally I would just use `new ImageIcon(aClass.class.getResource("/path/with/image.png"))`.)
What would be a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is mostly used for small graphics used on a website where it is expensive to load a lot of resources seperatly.

In your case I would see no benefit in using this technique.